# Semantic of comma-separated values with bison

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to give a semantic value to a list of comma-separated values. In fact, I have defined the reduction rules for bison using

```
commasv : exp
        | commasv "," exp
```

where `exp` its a number or a variable or a function pointer or, also, a commasv token with its respective syntax and semantic rules. The type of `exp` is double so the type of `commasv` must be double.

The thing is that I want to store the list in order to use it, for example, on a function call. For instance

```
h = create_object()
compute_list(h,1,cos(3.14159))
```

will give the expected result of a certain `compute_list` function.

As basis bison file I've used mfcalc example from the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Multi_002dfunction-Calc) and I replaced the `yylex` function by other one generated [using flex](https://gist.github.com/4699166). By now I can do things like

```
pi = 3.14159
sin(pi)
ln(exp(5))
```

with the modified version of `yylex` function with flex but I want use the comma-separated values with function calls, lists creation and more.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You'll need a LIFO or FIFO structure depending on the associativity of your `,` operand. (stack or queue). In my case it was an stack, but it could be different for you.

Answer (score 1):

Then create a list to store the results in. Instead of having the result of the `commasv` rule return an actual value, have it return the list head.

In general, as soon as you get a somewhat moderately advanced grammar (like it incorporating things like lists), you can no longer really use values to represent the parsing, but have to go over to some sort of [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).